# Convert mysql result (big associative array) to nested arrays

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a simple query like this

```
SELECT hometeam.name AS hometeamName, hometeam.shortname AS hometeamShortName, 
       roadteam.name AS roadteamName, roadteam.shortname AS roadteamShortName, 
       smatch.startdate

FROM smatch 
    JOIN team hometeam
        ON smatch.hometeamid = hometeam.uid
    JOIN team roadteam
        ON smatch.roadteamid = roadteam.uid
```

which be default returns a one dimensional array, like this:

```
array(5) {
     ["homeTeamName"] => "Brasil"
     ["homeTeamShortName"] => "BRA"
     ["roadTeamName"] => "Norway"
     ["roadTeamShortName"]=> "NOR"
     ["startdate"]=> "1309709700"
}
```

Question is, is there a **mysql-way** to let the result be a nested array, with a **structure** like the following?

```
result => 
    hometeam =>
        name
        shortname
    roadteam =>
        name
        shortname
    startdate
```

And if not, is there a (php) **post processing best practice** to do this conversion?

Many thanks,
Robson

Comment: Please add what the resulting rows look like, will be easier to respond then. A few will suffice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there's a way to directly get the result you want, but to generate that array after the query shouldn't be hard.

Something like this?

```
foreach($rows as $row) {
  $resultArray[] = array(
    'hometeam' => array(
      'name' => $row['homeTeamName'], 
      'shortname' => $row['homeTeamShortName']
      ),
    'roadteam' => array(
      'name' => $row['roadTeamName'], 
      'shortname' => $row['roadTeamShortName']
      ),
    'startdate' => $row['startdate']
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

MySQL (or any database) has no concept of arrays.

The only way I can think of is that you'd need to do it in a Stored Procedure and serialise the result in some way - essentially creating a serialised string... wich you'd then need to re-construct the array from.

However, would be better doing this in PHP to be honest, the gain from doing it in an SP will be minimal. Will be more efficient to query the main and then query within using loops PHP-side.

Comment: The PostrgreSQL has concept of arrays.

Answer (score 1):

You have to fetch the result in [PDO::FETCH_CLASS](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php) mode.

by specifying the [__set()](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php)-method respectively you can store the result-field-data how ever you like.

This class should also extend [ArrayAccess](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/class.arrayaccess.php) so you can access it like an array or have it return one.

Comment: Good call, forgot about PDO for a moment :)